# Can't upgrade Wordpress because another progress is running

Tags: php, wordpress

It was a long story, I was installed WPMU for the very first time.

And when WPMU was merged into Wordpress, I've upgrade my site using Wordpress.

Now I've tried update my site to the latest Wordpress version.

And system kept notify me "Another update process is running"

I've googled by myself, all results pointed out that "wp_options" table in Wordpress database have value "core_updater.lock"

BUT!

my database don't have the single table named 'wp_options' instead I have 'wp_1_options','wp_2_options' like that.

And all of them don't have value 'core_updater.lock'

Now, what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Login to phpmyadmin into your database  find the table **wp-option** delete

`core_updater.lock`

for more check this link

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224989/get-rid-of-another-update-is-currently-in-progress

Hope it will work for you

Comment: No, as I've already said I don't have a table named wp-option, and further more I don't have core_updater.lock in all of my wp_*_options tables